# How to add assertions to the request inside while controller of Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm using a jmeter script with while controller condition as

```
${__javaScript("${status}"=="Progress")}
```

Followed by one http request and from that request again I will extract the status.
If the status is progress it will contine one http request inside loop else if the status success it will exit the loop. But i want to add assertion to ensure whether I get the status as success in the http request or not.

Because if i use assertion as Success in that http sampler, it checks all the reqest and obviously it will return false, and i need to add assertion only to the final http sampler of the while controller.

And so I can get error percentage with failing request in aggregate report and view results tree . Can anyone share your ideas please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to verify if `${status}` variable value is `Progress` **OR** `Success`

1. Add Response Assertion as a child of the HTTP Request sampler
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Apply to: -> JMeter Variable -> `status`
   - Pattern Matching Rules: `Matches`
   - Patterns to Test: `Progress|Success`

     [image: JMeter Response Assertion 2 Clauses]

Given you use "Matches" rule JMeter will treat the pattern as a [Perl5-style regular expression](http://www.pcre.org/) so if `${status}` variable will be equal to `Success` or `Progress` the sampler will pass and otherwise it will be marked as failed.

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article to learn more about using Assertions in Jmeter tests.